# Python Cassandra - TypeError: object of type 'UUID' has no len()

Tags: python, cassandra, prepared-statement, uuid

I want to share with this error to run Cassandra prapered statement on Python.

Here is my initial code:

```
def loadMetricIdsByGroupId(self, group_id):
    return self.session.execute(self.load_metrics_by_group_for_group_id_stmt, (group_id))
```

All sounds good.

But at run time Ii got this:

```
  File "C:\Soft\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cassandra\query.py", line 501, in bind
    return BoundStatement(self).bind(values)
  File "C:\Soft\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cassandra\query.py", line 599, in bind
    value_len = len(values)
  TypeError: object of type 'UUID' has no len()
```

Regards,
Ali

Comment: If you solved your own question, you still can post it as an answer, this way the question will be marked as solved

Answer (score 1):

I read this documentation :

https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/python-driver/3.19/getting_started/

And guess what?

I should use [] instead of () for group_id parameter.

```
def loadMetricIdsByGroupId(self, group_id):
return self.session.execute(self.load_metrics_by_group_for_group_id_stmt, [group_id])
```

By the way I spent a long time (1 hour) searching the web before I come back to the official documentation.

The problem is now solved.

Kind Regards,
Ali